# Connecting Visual studio Code to AWS Ec2 instance gives Timeout in VSC But works from ssh clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-code

I have created the ec2 instance for my education purpose via the link provided from my university.

I have done all the procedures and now can connect to the server from ssh client (i am using xshell).

Now I want to connect to the server from Visual studio code. Everywhere I look on the web, the routine procedure of creating the SSH config file and providing the path of the config file in the VSC's remote development setup for connection is given. I have done all that and I still get a timeout and connection fails. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Provide ssh command like: `ssh hello@21.12.114.12 -A`.

And just select a path to save configuration, eg. `[HOME]/.ssh/config`. It's a local file.